# Setting up Cairo Project

Tags: speech-recognition, cairo

I am trying to set up the Cairo-0.3 project and my rserver.sh, receiver.sh and transmitter.sh are successfully running but when i try to run execute the demo-recog.sh (A demo program in cairo) i get :

```
Received an unhandled SIP response status code (ignoring it): 183 : Session progress

2012-07-16 18:01:31,931 INFO  {main} org.speechforge.cairo.demo.recog.RecognitionClient
 Received the SIP Response.  
2012-07-16 18:01:31,931 INFO  {main} org.speechforge.cairo.demo.recog.RecognitionClient  
  invite : org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SdpMessage@1e61363  
java.lang.NullPointerException  
2012-07-16 18:01:32,067 WARN  {Thread-7} org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPPlayer  
 playSource(): encountered unexpected exception:    
javax.media.NoDataSourceException: Error instantiating class:   com.sun.media.protocol.dsound.DataSource : java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(Manager.java:1012)  
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPPlayer.playSource(RTPPlayer.java:110)  
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.NativeMediaClient$TransmitThread.run(NativeMediaClient.java:105)
 Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.RuntimeException: playSource() encountered unexpected exception  
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPPlayer.playSource(RTPPlayer.java:153)  
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.NativeMediaClient$TransmitThread.run(NativeMediaClient.java:105)
Caused by: javax.media.NoDataSourceException: Error instantiating class:   com.sun.media.protocol.dsound.DataSource : java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(Manager.java:1012)  
    at org.speechforge.cairo.rtp.RTPPlayer.playSource(RTPPlayer.java:110)  
    ... 1 more  
2012-07-16 18:01:42,085 WARN  {main} org.speechforge.cairo.demo.recog.RecognitionClient
 org.mrcp4j.client.MrcpInvocationException: MRCP response contains an error code, the request invocation did not complete successfully.

org.mrcp4j.client.MrcpInvocationException: MRCP response contains an error code, the request invocation did not complete successfully.  
    at org.mrcp4j.client.MrcpChannel.sendRequest(MrcpChannel.java:143)
    at   org.speechforge.cairo.demo.recog.RecognitionClient.doRecognize(RecognitionClient.java:163)
    at   org.speechforge.cairo.demo.recog.RecognitionClient.main(RecognitionClient.java:346)

2012-07-16 18:01:42,091 INFO  {main} org.speechforge.cairo.sip.SimpleSipAgent
 Sent a SIP BYE.
```

I am not able to understand what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and configure Java Media Framework in order to run this software. See installation instructions in README:

> ### Installation
>
> 1. Extract Cairo
>      To install Cairo, extract all files from the binary distribution archive to a directory of your ch
> 2. Download and Install JMF 2.1.1   Cairo requires Java Media Framework (JMF) version 2.1.1. which can be downloaded here:
>      http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html
>      Download and run the JMF installer that corresponds to your specific
>      operating system.  This will

Comment: This exception says you didn't install it properly. Maybe you didn't define the environment variable as described in the documentation.